# Why does stack overflow reset the 15 seconds comment timer when attempting to make a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

Stack overflow now says (paraphrased) "only 1 comment allowed every 15 seconds; timer has been reset".

Doesn't this result in increased frustration with no apparent advantage? It also potentially grants an advantage to spam-bots (who keep a 15-second timer) over humans. What is the purpose of resetting the timer?

Is it because the timer is meant to prevent bandwidth saturation rather than to prevent spam? That would explain a lot

Comment: This ******* timer is the biggest source of frustration I find on SO. How can we make it clear enough we **need** the timer to stop being reset ?

Comment: I have been on the low quality review queue and for code-only answers I have a boilerplate comment. I got hit by this timer. Perhaps I should not robo-review, however I passed two surprising review audits, so I don't seem to be too bad. :-/

Answer (score 5):

It is designed to be intentionally frustrating:

> [That's nothing compared to the time collectively wasted by reading (multiple!) comments with less than 25 seconds of thought put into them.. write once, read many.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35443/if-i-cant-comment-for-30-more-seconds-why-is-the-add-comment-button-enabled/35450#comment78373_35450)

The intent is *not* to prevent bots from flooding comments, but rather to discourage *people* from posting multiple comments *period*.

[There is some debate over whether this is a good idea.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164048/please-make-the-multiple-comment-timer-less-annoying-non-resetting-etc) By which I mean to say, everyone who has ever encountered it hates it with a passion, while some of those who haven't don't care.

Personally, I have mixed feelings about the timer; on the one hand, I hate it when folks post multiple, back-to-back comments. On the other hand, I like that seeing multiple, back-to-back comments provides me with an indicator that this is probably someone who enjoys arguing more than they do reading, which then frees me up to go do something else rather than responding to them.

[Note that moderators often have legitimate reasons to post multiple comments quickly.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86784/lift-or-reduce-the-comment-rate-limiting-timer-for-moderators)

Comment: Still as frustrating.

Comment: Even with a timeout of only 5 seconds (I wasted about 10 seconds resetting the timer on that one...)

Comment: Only on Stack Overflow is a high WPM a *disadvantage*.

Comment: Since you can only ping one person per comment, it is sometimes necessary to write two or three comments in order to notify different people who commented. If you could ping multiple people in one comment, I think the frustration with this timer would mostly disappear.

Comment: Regular people who can just type fast (like me) can make multiple high-quality comments replying to different people in less than 15 seconds.

Comment: I'm *sure* all of you who think this is a good idea always take > 25 seconds to think through every response of yours when you're talking to your peers in real life.

Comment: @Mehrdad: SO comments are like being a library: if you talk unnecessarily then people will shush you. If I'm making a remark to my peers more than once per 15 seconds in a place where I'm not supposed to be chatting in the first place, then I'm doing something wrong. That said, I frequently trigger the time limit for noticing a typo in a comment as I post it, and correcting it too fast. This time limit does *not* help me to think more carefully about my typo corrections, so, whatever.

Comment: What really bugs me is the timer on "voting" comments, and the fact that it applies to deletions.  If I agree with someone that a comment thread needs to be cleaned up, I should be able to remove my comments to that thread as fast as I can click.  The timer is actually contributing to the presence of chatty comment threads.

Comment: Why the timer *reset*? I disagree with the timer = quality argument, but even if I did agree, 30 or 45 seconds if you miscount is way too long. All it does is encourage you to lose your train of thought.

Comment: I like to comment on multiple answers. Sometimes four different people miss the same crucial point of a question...

Comment: The problem I have with this "frustrating design" is that I type comments in text editor and proof read it once and copy-paste it (usually the same for my answers too). So when I see out "x chars too long" in comments, I try to split into 2 comments and I have to count seconds and *wait* for a comment into which I have already put enough thought into. *[..]everyone who has ever encountered it hates it with a passion [..]* -- include me there please!